# What are STF lenses?

Tags: lens, terminology, sony, lens-design

What are STF (smooth transition focus) lenses? How much do they differ from other fast lenses? What artistic techniques are done with them?
For example Sony has an a-mount 135mm F2.8 [T4.5] STF. What is their specialty?
Also what does T4.5 mean ?

Comment: Related: [How does the Sony 135 F2.8 \[T4.5\] STF twin aperture lens design work?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/42291/11924)

Comment: Also related: [How does an apodization filter improve bokeh?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/54156/11924)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

STF stands for "Smooth Transition Focus", and is a Sony-specific* term indicating that the lens includes an [apodization filter](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/54156/how-does-an-apodization-filter-improve-bokeh) to create smooth [bokeh](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/2706/what-is-bokeh-exactly) (out-of-focus blur) — and smooth bokeh is generally considered to be [the best bokeh](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/52516/what-is-considered-high-quality-bokeh). So, you'd generally use it for non-studio portraiture or in other cases where that blur is an important artistic element.

Other lensmakers use different terms; for example, Fujifilm designates their lens with this feature "[APD](http://www.fujifilm.com/products/digital_cameras/x/fujinon_lens_xf56mmf12_r_apd/)".

Note the [t-stop](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/21940/what-is-t-number-t-stop) designation of T4.5. This indicates that the actual transmission of light at the widest aperture is that of a theoretical f/4.5 lens — even though the effective maximum aperture is f/2.8. That's because about [a stop](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/15706/what-is-one-stop) is lost to the filter. (Fujifilm's f/1.2 APD lens is similarly limited in this way, with a t-stop of 1.7, again about one stop lost.)

Read more about t-stops at [What is T-number / T-stop?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/21940/what-is-t-number-t-stop). This concept is used for any light loss (which *all* lenses invariably have, since they're made of real-world materials), but normally the difference is small enough that we just ignore it — see [Why are DSLR lenses measured in F stops instead of T stops?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/79478/why-are-dslr-lenses-measured-in-f-stops-instead-of-t-stops) for more on why. But with the apodization filter, there's enough of a difference that it can be important to be aware.
Any through-the-lens autoexposure program mode will take this into account automatically; if you are doing manual metering and calculations, you should figure it in (although of course these digital days it's easier to guess and check than worry about the numbers).

---

<sub>* Previously, a Minolta-specific term, and then Sony bought Minolta's camera business....</sub>